# Best Practice for Multiple Zones in ANSYS Design Modeler for a 3D Structured Mesh for Fluent Simulation

Tags: cfd, ansys-workbench, meshing, fluent

I am building a structured mesh in a rectangular domain to model the flow over a wing with impinging jets at the root over the surface in the spanwise direction.

I've tried building unstructured meshes with inflation layers using the fluent meshing tool but with mixed results and little ability to control the mesh when attempting a convergence study. So, I decided to make everything rectangular and manually build it in Design Modeler and ANSYS's meshing tool. But I'm running into some snags, and that might be because my methodology is wrong. (*All my dimensions are described with symbols here. If it helps actually to put the values in, I will add them.*)

To start, here is a screenshot of my domain in Design Modeler.
[image: Geometry]
Here are the steps I took making this since the image probably doesn't help as it stands.

1. I drew a rectangle (10*b* by 10*b*) for my domain on the XY plane, as shown. Then I extruded it symmetrically a distance 10*b* in the +/- z direction.
   [image: Sketch1]
2. After that, I made a new plane, shifted a distance *r* in the z direction, and made the sketch for my wing (height *t* in y by width *c* in x). Then I made an extrude cut in the z direction of this sketch a distance *b*. The extruded cut is a little hard to see now, but in the final image below, I have some of the bodies around the void for the wing.

[image: Plane4]
[image: Sketch2]
[image: Wing Void]

3. Now initially, I wanted to make a rectangular face where the flow from my jets would enter from an inlet boundary condition on the green face shown. But I could not make the extruded slices I wanted, so I had to offset that face with a separate Plane and sketch. The blue x's denote edges on the desired face, and the red x's denote edges of the actual face. **So the second image is the actual face where the inlet is.**

[image: Desired Inlet Face][image: Actual Inlet Face]
[image: Tube Void]

4. Since I wanted a structured mesh, which would mean I needed to match face pairs to avoid stretching, I had to subdivide the larger domain into smaller ones. However, taking into account that i) I have the void for my wing, ii) the void for my "tubes" where one face will be an inlet, and iii) a gap between the two actually make the slices; when I make all the subdivisions I am left with **58 total! And each of them has 6 faces that need to be given individual named selections.**

Here is one last image showing the void for my wing (red), the gap (green), and the void (blue) where the flow inlet (black) will be.
[image: Mid-Section]

**So my thought is that there must be a way to make this geometry in Design Modeler without as many bodies and still get a structured mesh. I need to have a large rectangular domain, and a void for my wing and *as far as I am aware*, a space between the wing and the void where one of the faces is an inlet.**

I've considered making the inlet face just a 2D surface, drastically reducing the total number of bodies. But I don't know how or even if I can do that. *Until then, I'll be labeling each named selection manually.*

I'll do my best to field any other questions. Thank you.

**Addendum:** I forgot to say that I'm trying to use a multizone meshing method and match control, but nothing I do seems to work. I keep getting errors. I tried it on a smaller piece with only three bodies and multizone seems to work, giving me a structured mesh, but I can't apply Match Control to different faces on the same body.

**Addendum 2:** I found a video that talks about Match Control [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpM92mQYsYM). It doesn't specifically have a particular method to use but after playing around some, I was able to get a Cyclic Match Control to work by **changing the Multi-Zone method to a Sweep Method and creating a new coordinate system.** I put a face meshing on **three faces** of the smaller geometry I'm testing and edge sizings. The first four images show the process on the test geometry. But afterward, I tried making a pair of edge sizings with bias on the remaining edge, but the match control would only work if the edge sizing were defined for only one edge. And then, when I look at the "matched" face, the mesh doesn't match. See the last two pictures (notice one face doesn't even have quad elements at the edge). *Hopefully this helps document more what I'm seeing and can help with a diagnosis and solution.*

[image: Face Sizing]
[image: Edge Sizing]
[image: Match Control]
[image: Success Mesh Test]
[image: Edge Sizing 3]
[image: Unsuccessful Mesh]

Comment: Don't you need a finer mesh in the wing proximity? You cannot do that with structured mesh and "box" parts. You could consider subdivision into a more general cuboids which would stretch out further from the wing. Also is the foil rectangular or will there be an additional unstructured transitional fluid domain around the actual wing? Regarding Named Selections, you could create them using Worksheet it that is an option (it works well in Mechanical, I'm not sure about DM though).

Comment: 1) Yes I need a finer mesh near the wing. I'm more interested in generating a mesh at all before worrying about making a good one. I don't see how you can say I cannot make a structured mesh in each of the bodies around the void does not make. The foil is rectangular, look at my sketches under step 2. I've already created all my named selections in DM and they transferred to Mechanical, but if you can provide information about this Worksheet option I'll take anything that makes the process faster. Thanks.

Comment: You can make structured mesh, but it has very limited local refinement options. My point is you don't need to constrain yourself to rectangular shapes, structured mesh can be done also in "warped" rectangles (general cuboids in 3D), which might be more suitable for such domain. Worksheet option in Mechanical allows you to generate a Name Selection using a list of defined steps such as select all faces with centroids at specific coordinate, convert these into lines, etc. It can be very efficient if desired entities share something in common, which you can use to select them automatically.

Comment: Thank you @TomášLétal this is helpful. But I don't know how to implement all of this. Can you recommend some guided tutorials or would you be interested in jumping into a chat to help explain this in more detail?

Comment: For example, 1) what do you mean by general cuboids in 3D, and 2) do you have specific tutorials for how to use the Worksheet option? A possible third thing to discuss that I mentioned in my question is how to create the inlet over my wing.

Comment: A simpler, 2D version of my suggestion would be subdividing the domain into trapezoids instead of rectangles, for example like [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315849717_Numerical_Study_on_Flow_around_Four_Square-Arranged_Cylinders_at_Low_Reynolds_Numbers/figures?lo=1). Such approach provides additional mesh controls. Now in your 3D problem, you could use cuboid volumes with a small rectangular side at the wing and the large opposite side at the outer boundary of the domain.

Comment: Regarding generating Named Selections using Worksheet, Mechanical will probably not help, but the same feature should exist in Fluent. [This is how it looks like](https://courses.ansys.com/index.php/courses/high-resolution-fe-model-of-bone/lessons/physics-setup-lesson-5-14/topic/3-named-selection/).

Comment: I will follow up on these links and see if they're helpful. Thank you.